# Visual Studio 2013 error on build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Does anyone know what this error is in VS 2013 C# ?

> Error 1   Parameter "SearchPaths" has invalid value "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Tasks  WpfApplication1

I keep getting this error on compiling and cant figure out where it comes from.

Thanks

Comment: Does it give you a line number?

Comment: no line number error. I even created a new project and compiled, same error. No clue. I forgot to mention that this is a WPF project

Comment: Try to repair your installation.

Comment: Try enabling msbuild diagnostics and seeing where that error pops up.  Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions.  Set the MSBuild verbosity to something higher than minimal and see where that error is occuring

Comment: The ResolveAssemblyReference task, no doubt.  And yes, it is not a valid path, " WpfApplication1" should not be there.  Probably a missing end quote for the SQL path, hard to find.  Search the registry first.

Comment: so i did raise the MSBuild verbosity to "Detail" and the error is in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets Line 1635

Upon opening this reference line 1635 looks like this
SearchPaths="$(AssemblySearchPaths)"

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing an issue similar to this, only the error included several other files, searching I found a post where a guy corrected the problem by simply deleting the "obj" folder on the project's folder and building again, I tried that and it worked great.

I don't know if this will solve the OP's problem or if it's too late, but I hope this solution helps anyone struggling with similar issues.

P.S.: If you don't feel comfortable deleting the folder, try renaming it, when you build "obj" folder will be generated again.